# Battery stuck at 0% and acpi showing last-full-capacity as negative

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, battery, acpi

My Asus laptop is around 3.5 years old, and I have been using Ubuntu extensively until the hard drive got corrupted (bad sectors started increasing). You can refer [Ubuntu 20.04 going into Read-only filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399989/ubuntu-20-04-going-into-read-only-filesystem) where I asked a related question.

I have been using Windows ever since, and everything was fine. Windows is mounted on SSD, and the issue of the bad sector did not affect Windows. But I recently started using Ubuntu again, without replacing the disk. I had forgotten about the bad sectors problem. There was a new problem waiting. It was that the battery always shows 0% while charging (this had not happened when I was using Windows), and shuts down when I switch off charging. This problem is happening in Windows as well, the charge is stuck at 0% while charging and shuts down when removed from charging.

The output from `acpi -i` shows that the last-full-capacity is negative. I think this is a software problem (maybe some corrupted data from the hard disk's bad sectors updated the BIOS info), and not a hardware problem, though I might be wrong. This output is as follows:

```
Battery 0: Charging, 0%, charging at zero rate - will never fully charge.
Battery 0: design capacity 3649 mAh, last full capacity -36 mAh = -1%
```

The output from `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` gives the following output:

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Wednesday 08 February 2023 04:54:07 PM (86 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         0 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             11.55 V
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

BIOS version is: `X430FA.308`

Is this actually my battery dying, or is it just some software/BIOS issue that could be corrected without buying a new battery? And if it is just a software issue, could you please guide me on how to solve the issue? I am presently a student who will be graduating this May. I plan to use my laptop primarily for coursework and running some NLP models for my projects. I don't plan to buy a new laptop before May, and might buy a new laptop later, since I believe replacing both HDD and battery in this laptop could actually be very expensive and a new laptop would be much better.

Comment: The battery is dead. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: It happens on both Windows as Ubuntu. It is therefor really a hardware problem.